Who is Yadulus?
This post contains references to the newest patch's quest and content, so there might be spoilers.
During Operation: Belly of the Beast, following a conversation between Parvos Granum and Ordis, we saw a figure not previously encountered (and for whom google searches yield no results).


"Taking care of my wounds. See, Mother, needlework was useful."

And shortly after:


"Dead deadity dead. Hahaha."

Right after killing the Sister:


"Turning this place into a boneyard!"

That's the last we see or hear of him.
As far as we were able to tell, we did not have a Stalker in the game - there was no flicker at any point.
Speculation
His first dialogue contains "Mother". It's unclear who that is meant to reference, but given that

 towards the end of Jade Shadows we see the Stalker receiving the infant Sirius/Orion after Jade departs

maybe Yadulus is connected to Jade/Stalker in a more familial way?
The whimsical but simultaneously sinister nature of his speech also reminds me of the Man in the Wall, though I have no reason to think they are related or connected.

It turns out to most likely be an on-call crew member. See this official forum thread for screenshots with examples.
